# Dynamic types with use context selector

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-context

I am using [use-context-selector](https://github.com/dai-shi/use-context-selector) in my react/typescript application and I am struggling with having some dynamic types.

Here is a context that I have:

```js
type AbilityContextType = {
  attack: () => number;
  defend: () => number;
  retreat: () => void;
  advance: () => void;
};
```

Here is a hook that I have which makes it easier for consumers of my application to consume whatever they need from the ability context.

```js
import { createContext, useContextSelector } from 'use-context-selector';

const AbilityContext = createContext<AbilityContextType>();

const useAbilityContext = <T extends (keyof AbilityContextType)[]>(
  ...keys: T
) => useContextSelector(AbilityContext, ...keys);
```

And here is an example usage of said hook. The types are all working as expected.

```js
const [attack, retreat] = useAbilityContext('attack', 'retreat');
```

My issue is that I am not a fan of having types inlined in my `useAbilityContext` function. I like to have functions and the types of functions as separated as possible for better readability. Is it possible to simplify the type of `useAbilityContext` by maybe moving it into its own interface/type? I've tried but it's just not working.

Preferabley, I'd like my `useAbilityContext` hook to look like so:

```js
// interface UseAbilityHookType { ??? }
// type UseAbilityHookType = ???;

const useAbilityContext: UseAbilityHookType = (...keys) => useContextSelector(AbilityContext, ...keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a type that describes a generic function. Something like:

```
type UseAbilityHookType =
  <T extends (keyof AbilityContextType)[]>(...keys: T) => AbilityContextType[T[number]]

// usage
const useAbilityContext: UseAbilityHookType =
  (...keys) => useContextSelector(AbilityContext, ...keys);
```

(I am somewhat unsure of the return type, but I guess that's up to you.)